# Datagridview column name not changing

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, multiple-columns

Here is my code, I don't think there is anything wrong with it, but my column names still remain the same from the ones in mysql.

```
Private Sub DGVShareholder_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVShareholder.CellContentClick

    Me.DGVShareholder.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Company Name"
    Me.DGVShareholder.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Position"
    Me.DGVShareholder.Columns(3).HeaderText = "NI"
    Me.DGVShareholder.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Forename"
    Me.DGVShareholder.Columns(5).HeaderText = "Surname"
    Me.DGVShareholder.Columns(6).HeaderText = "D.O.B"
    Me.DGVShareholder.Columns(7).HeaderText = "Address Line 1"
    Me.DGVShareholder.Columns(8).HeaderText = "City"
    Me.DGVShareholder.Columns(9).HeaderText = "Postcode"
    Me.DGVShareholder.Columns(10).HeaderText = "Email"
    Me.DGVShareholder.Columns(11).HeaderText = "Phone Number"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you change them in this event? Does this event occur?

Comment: Do you have any cells of type DataGridViewButtonCell or DataGridViewLinkCell? The CellContentClick event is only fired when clicking on those cells. I agree with DonA, weird place to specify the header text unless it needs to be changed by something?

Comment: I know it is the wrong place, but I was experimenting as I don't know where to place it?

Comment: Why you don't use a designer. There you can create predefined columns with different Header and DataPropertyName(Column name from database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see why this doesn't work. I regularly change the heading of `DataGridView`s after I set the `DataSource` to be a table dumped from an `SQL` query

See if the `DataGridView` is being overwritten again after you change the headings or try and apply something like a `DataSourceChanged`  or `DataBindingComplete` event so the headings are modified after changes to the data

```
Private Sub DGVShareholder_DataSourceChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DGVShareholder.DataSourceChanged

    Dim i = 0
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In Me.DGVShareholder.Columns
        column.HeaderText = i
        i += 10
    Next

End Sub
```